# How to Install all the default packages by group Using the Local YUM repo

Tags: rhel, yum, http

I created a Local HTTP YUM repo. I can install the individual packages. But is there a way to install packages in the available groups?

When I tried to install using groups, it give me this message:

```
[root@mainserver ~]#  yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Setting up Group Process
Warning: Group Development Tools does not exist.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the command `yum grouplist` to determine if you even have any groups available in your yum repo.

If you want groups in your repo you'll need to populate its definition using the following commands:

1. Create the group

   ```
   $ yum-groups-manager -n "My Group" --id=mygroup --save=mygroups.xml \
        --mandatory yum glibc rpm
   ```

   This will result in a file, `mygroups.xml` being generated, for example:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE comps PUBLIC "-//Red Hat, Inc.//DTD Comps info//EN" "comps.dtd">
   <comps>
     <group>
      <id>mygroup</id>
      <default>False</default>
      <uservisible>True</uservisible>
      <display_order>1024</display_order>
      <name>My group</name>
      <description></description>
       <packagelist>
         <packagereq type="mandatory">glibc</packagereq>
         <packagereq type="mandatory">rpm</packagereq>
         <packagereq type="mandatory">yum</packagereq>
       </packagelist>
     </group>
   </comps>
   ```
2. Create group in repo

   When creating your repo use the following command to populate the group:

   ```
   $ createrepo -g /path/to/mygroups.xml /srv/my/repo
   ```

#### References

- [Yum groups and repositories](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/YumGroups)